# What is the best way to return a view to an ArraySeq?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.13

Ideally when working from an `IndexedSeqView` over an `ArraySeq`, there should be only one array copy (or at least only one new array allocated) when converting the view back to an `ArraySeq` after some manipulation.
What is the most performant way to get back to an `ArraySeq`?

A couple options that come to mind:

```
ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray(view.toArray)
```

seems promising, but does `.toArray` know the view is over an array and can use fast array copies to populate the new array?

```
ArraySeq.from(view)
```

I'm guessing this is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way would be

```
view.to(ArraySeq)
```

Comment: If I'm following this right, it looks like this ends up calling `ArraySeq.from`. Although that could be wrong (it calls `ArraySeq.fromSpecific` first, but I haven't found where that's implemented yet) so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html), the recommended way is calling `view.force` to evaluate the transformations for the collection.

Comment: That was deprecated in 2.13, now it just returns an `IndexedSeq`